# How to make an emulator for Windows CE operating system targeting specific hardware

Tags: embedded, windows-ce, emulation

I think this is a common problem for all developers using **Windows CE 6.0 operating systems on specific hardware**. I have a client that needs a custom operating system for its ICOP PDX-089T PC with Touch panel, that is based on DM&P SoC CPU Vortex86DX-1GHz.

I do not have the hardware with me, so every time I make a change I have to send at least the NK.bin file, or the whole ghost image to the client to make the tests for.

Is there any way to build a custom Windows CE emulator to add it to Visual Studio 2005 for testing or may be a custom virtual machine to launch it through VMWare or Virtual PC?

I tried some guidelines from the internet to build one, but every effort in making one resulted in hanging up my PC.

Does anybody have similar needs and some solution?

*Note:* The emulator I need is for Vortex86DX processor and ICOP board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft abandoned the x86 Emulator some time ago, choosing to support only an ARM emulator (the BSP ships in the box with Platform Builder 6.0). This means that you can't create an emulator for the x86 processor, though I'm hard-pressed to think of a scenario where you'd really need to and where just getting hardware isn't a better solution for anyway.

There is [a BSP for doing Virtual PC OS builds](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/CE6VirtualPCBSP) that would run on x86.  It's not had much activity in some time, and I've never tried it, so YMMV.

Comment: I can describe to you one scenario. The mine. Suppose you are half world appart from your client who has the hardware and hired you to make a simple custom Windows CE operating system to run only one custom made application. Every change in the code or in OS you can only suppose how it will react on the real target machine. Sending the hardware to me is very expensive. On the other hand I tried to make a Virtual PC OS but finished with frozen Virtual machine. Yes it starts loading the NK.bin but stops at 97% and thats it. Maybe I made a mistake but I don't know where.

Comment: A PDX089 is about $450 in one-off pricing (maybe a little less, or more depending on options and screen size).  If your time is worth much at all (I assume that you bill the customer for your time), then the time spend trying to build a VPC or emulator, plus the opportunity cost of you not working on the actual problem during those hours, I think would quickly outweigh the cost of hardware.

Comment: The project is set to fixed amount that is much less then $450 ... The software is finished and tested on similar hardware but remains these little problems. Buying the PDX will be worth if will have similar project in future.